# Overriding the overflow menu style through XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to change the the the `textColor` of the overflow menu items.

So far I have only found code explained with reflection and/or setting a Factory on the LayoutInflater that checks if the name of the view is some internal `menuItem`, returning a TextView with the right styles.

Surely there should be a style in the theme that can be overridden. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing through a lot of StackOverflow questions and answers and blog posts, I finally found the correct style to override.

In the style.xml or theme.xml where you define the theme of your app, include:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/OverflowTextStyle</item>
    </style>
</rescources>
```

The style attribute you want to override is `android:actionBarWidgetTheme`. Include the item in the main theme declaration. (I first expected it to be defined in the definition for `android:actionBarStyle`, but that *is not* where it belongs; it's simply an item inside your application theme.)

Now all we have to do is declare the `OverflowTextStyle` style somewhere:

```
<resources>
    <style name="OverflowTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```